# forEach() call fails to compile

Tags: vue.js, compiler-errors, nuxt.js

The following portion of code compiles correctly with `Vue CLI 2`, but within my `Nuxt` project it doesn't:

```
// Populate row with times + total of times at the end of the row
let total = 0
['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'].forEach(day => {
  const temp = weekTimes.find(x => x.date === this[day])
  if (temp) {
    this[day + 'Time'] = temp.hours
    total += parseInt(temp.hours)
  } else {
    this[day + 'Time'] = ''
  }
})
```

The third line (`['mon', 'tue'...`) is associated with the following compiling errors:

> Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 10 Unexpected newline
>   between object and [ of property access
>
> Unexpected use of comma operator
>
> Expected parentheses around arrow function argument having a body with
>   curly braces

Yet it's valid ES6 code, so why does the compiler have a problem with it?

Comment: Those appear to be lint errors - are you asking how to configure eslint for your project?

Comment: No I just want to know why these errors show up if the code is valid

Comment: Because either your editor or your project or both are applying [eslint](https://eslint.org/) to your code. These warnings don't indicate that your code will not execute, they indicate that your code does not conform to the particular lint rules being applied.

Comment: If you don't know what linting is, it is essentially your computer standing over your shoulder nagging when you do not properly write the code as you told it you would via [linting rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perils of omitting semi-colons.

This:

```js
let total = 0
['mon', 'tue'].forEach(day => {
```

will be treated as this:

```js
let total = 0['mon', 'tue'].forEach(day => {
```

The `0[...]` part will be treated as trying to access a property on the value `0`. Try running this example in your browser console:

```js
0['toFixed'](2)
```

This is just a way of calling the `toFixed` method on the value `0`, passing the argument 2.

The comma operator part of the error refers to the `'mon', 'tue'` section. Try typing this in your console:

```js
'mon', 'tue'
```

While it's rare to use the comma operator like this you should find that it evaluates to the last value, so `'tue'` in this case. So, using my earlier example, it's a bit like this:

```js
0['toString', 'toFixed'](2)
```

Here the `toString` is effectively ignored and it just calls `toFixed` like in my previous example. Linters will check for such uses of commas as they almost always result from a comma being incorrectly interpreted. As in your case it's usually intended to be a delimiter within an array rather than the comma operator.

So back to your code, this:

```js
let total = 0
['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun'].forEach(day => {
```

will be trying to access the `'sun'` property of the value `0`, which will be `undefined`. It will then try to call the `forEach` method on `undefined`, which will throw an error.

So while your code is valid it won't behave as expected. The linter is picking up on these mistakes and trying to help you to fix them.

The simplest solution is to insert a semi-colon.

This warning:

> Expected parentheses around arrow function argument having a body with curly braces

is just a linting rule. It expects you to write  `.forEach(day => {` as `.forEach((day) => {`. There is nothing wrong with the code from a correctness perspective, it really is just a linter imposing a code-style preference.